# mysql server max_connect_errors, logging

Tags: mysql

We have our mysql servers behind a load balancer which is masking the original IP address.

Is there any way we can log the connection requests in MySQL?

There is either a misconfigured app somewhere that is triggering authentication requests.  Increasing the max_connect_errors would be a hack... its better to find the incorrectly coded page.

Thanks

Comment: What's connecting to the db? PHP?

Comment: java, php, several ruby and python apps.

Comment: so far I've enabled the full mysql log... and am collecting data.  Hopefully greping through it I will be able to find the username which is failing.